# How to load controller in initialize using separated fxml files

Tags: java, javafx

I created 3 fxml files login first then the preloader and then my main application. During the preloader i load database stuff and images and some other tasks.

inside the preloader i created a method to load my main application like this

```
private void showMainProgram() throws IOException{


    mainStage = new Stage();
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    AnchorPane aplogin = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml").openStream());
    MainController controller = (MainController) fxmlLoader.getController();

    controller.setLoaderProperties(this);

    Scene scene = new Scene (aplogin) ;
    mainStage.setScene(scene);
    mainStage.setTitle("loading");
    mainStage.show();


}
```

Now what happen is the following :

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {
public LoaderController loaderController ;

@FXML ListView mylist ;
@FXML Label labelName ;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    System.out.println("This will happen first (1)");


    DoSomeStuff();

}    

 public void DoSomeStuff () {

     System.out.println("This will happen next (2)");

     // now here i will get a javafx.fxml.LoadException 
     //because my loadController is not yet set

     labelName.setText(loaderController.UserDTO.getName());

 }

 public void setLoaderProperties(LoaderController loaderController) {

     // I need this to happen first 
     System.out.println("This happens last (3)");

    this.loaderController = loaderController ;


}
```

I tried something like this :
But i think this creates a new loader controller. So i get a null exception.

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


    try {

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    VBox vboxLoader = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("loader.fxml").openStream());
    LoaderController loadcontroller = (LoaderController) fxmlLoader.getController();

    this.loaderController = loadcontroller;    





    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

      DoSomeStuff();

}
```

Comment: Call `DoSomeStuff` from the end of `setLoaderProperties`.

Comment: Omg.. Thank for saying this. You have no idea how long i was thinking in the wrong direction.. @JAtkin

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the problem

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {
public LoaderController loaderController ;

@FXML ListView mylist ;
@FXML Label labelName ;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    System.out.println("This will happen first (1)");


}    

 public void DoSomeStuff () {

     System.out.println("This will happen last(3)");

     labelName.setText(loaderController.UserDTO.getName());

 }

 public void setLoaderProperties(LoaderController loaderController) {

     // I need this to happen first 
     System.out.println("This wil happen next (2)");

    this.loaderController = loaderController ;

    // adding DoSomeStuff in the method  setLoaderProperties  
    // fixed the problem     

    DoSomeStuff();


}
```

Comment: What do you mean ? Do i not use already different controller for each FXML files ? Or do you mean using the controller inside another controller ? And how should i approach this if this is not correct ? Can you give a sample of what you are saying. @James_D

Comment: Ahem, yes, you're right. Somehow I completely misread your code, and thought `LoaderController` had a reference to another instance. Apologies. I'll delete my original comment as it will just confuse people (and is clearly nonsense).